# Will a PC4-21300 module be compatible with a PC4-19200 module?

Tags: memory, compatibility, latency, cas

I have two PC4-19200 modules (4Gb each) in my laptop. Both modules are by Hynix (HMA851S6AFR6N-UH) and have a CAS latency of 17.

I want to buy a single Kingston [module](https://www.mltrade.ru/catalog/modul-pamyati-Kingston-DDR4-SODIMM-16GB-KVR26S19D8-16-PC4-21300-2666MHz-CL17_1586947-078076.html) (KVR26S19D8/16, PC4-21300) but its indicated CAS latency is 19.

Will the Kingston module be compatible with the Hynix module, making up to a total of 20Gb, or will I have to remove both Hynix modules due to imcompatibility?

Here's my current memory config from CPU-Z (the second Hynix module has the same characteristics):

> [image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: @Ramhound - I've added all the details I knew, so it must be highly specific as is. Should I delete some information?

Comment: We cannot determine memory compatibility based on the information you have provided.

Comment: @Ramhound - what additional information should I gather? Or is it better just to delete the question, because there's no way of telling whether the units will work together?